# eval() versus if() -- is there a performance difference?

Tags: perl, if-statement, performance, eval

My question specifically is for Perl but I would like to be enlightened for most languages.

Is there an actual difference (performance-wise and efficiency-wise) between using an eval() function, versus an if() statement?

```
eval(-e /path/to/file) or die "file doesn't exist";
if (! -e /path/to/file) { die "file doesn't exist"; }
```

Comment: Um... that's an apples to cookies comparison if ever I saw one. Could we see a use case?

Comment: I edited my question. I know eval() evaluates a string as code but are my examples above correct?

Comment: Isn't that `eval` just redundant? I.e. couldn't you just do `(-e /path/to/file) or die "..."`?

Comment: I thought when you don't specify anything (like you did) it's just like eval'ing it. I guess my question is actually if `(-e /path/to/file)` is as efficient as `if (-e /path/to/file) {}`

Comment: First, this isn't valid perl. Second, that `eval` doesn't do what you think it does. It's `eval`ing the result of `-e /path/to/file`. Just use `-e "/path/to/file" or die "file doesn't exist";`. It's equivalent to the `if`.

Comment: It would help if you posted actual code; what you posted contains syntax errors because you didn't quote the file name.  There are two different forms of `eval`.  One compiles and evaluates a string containing Perl code (this is rarely useful), but that's not what you're doing here.  The other evaluates a block of code and allows you to trap exceptions (`die`s within the block set `$@`rather than killing the program), but you're not doing that here.  You need to read the documentation: `perldoc -f eval`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, don't micro-optimize like this.  It is far more important to write code that you can most easily follow the sense of.  Keeping this in mind will result in fewer bugs, and avoiding one bug is more important than saving a great number of nanoseconds.

That said, you can examine how perl compiles things like so:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e '-e "/path/to/file" or die "file doesn\x27t exist";'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <$> const[PV "/path/to/file"] s
4  <1> ftis sK/1
5  <|> or(other->6) vK/1
6      <0> pushmark s
7      <$> const[PV "file doesn't exist"] s
8      <@> die[t2] vK/1
9  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e 'if ( ! -e "/path/to/file") { die "file doesn\x27t exist"; }'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 3 -e:1) v:{
3  <$> const[PV "/path/to/file"] s
4  <1> ftis sK/1
5  <1> not sK/1
6  <|> and(other->7) vK/1
7      <0> enter v
8      <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
9      <0> pushmark s
a      <$> const[PV "file doesn't exist"] s
b      <@> die[t2] vK/1
c      <@> leave vKP
d  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

You can see some trivial extra operations involved in the second for the logical not of the result of -e, entering and leaving the `{}` block, and for having the die as a separate statement.  That separate statement can be useful; if you are stepping through the code in the debugger, it stops before dieing.

Using Perl 5.12+ or using `unless` instead of `if !` in older version of Perl removes the `not`:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e 'unless (-e "/path/to/file") { die "file doesn\x27t exist"; }'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 3 -e:1) v:{
3  <$> const[PV "/path/to/file"] s
4  <1> ftis sK/1
5  <|> or(other->6) vK/1
6      <0> enter v
7      <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
8      <0> pushmark s
9      <$> const[PV "file doesn't exist"] s
a      <@> die[t2] vK/1
b      <@> leave vKP
c  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

Using a statement modifier produces the same results as the `-e ... or die` code:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e 'die "file doesn\x27t exist" unless -e "/path/to/file";'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <$> const[PV "/path/to/file"] s
4  <1> ftis sK/1
5  <|> or(other->6) vK/1
6      <0> pushmark s
7      <$> const[PV "file doesn't exist"] s
8      <@> die[t2] vK/1
9  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: In newer Perls, `if (! ... )` becomes `or` too, even without using `unless`. The only difference between `if (! ... ) { ... }`  and `... or ...;` becomes the creation of the scope, something that can probably be done millions of times per second.

Comment: err, it shouldn't; that's a bug (makes a big difference in overloading)

Comment: Only if you have a class that behaves differently for `if!` and `unless`, and that's both silly and unsupported.

Comment: Um, no; imagine a class that has to do a lot of disk reads to come up with a count in numeric context but can quickly return 1 in boolean context.  Not at all silly or unsupported, but really messed up by this change.

Answer (score 2):

The string `eval` (`eval EXPR`) requires perl to compile your expression at runtime each time it is executed, which will be a lot more expensive than evaluating a pre-compiled expression. This is also true for any language that provides a similar run-time eval mechanism (JavaScript, Ruby, Python?)

In both the string `eval` and the block `eval` (`eval { BLOCK }`), perl sets up an error handler that sets `$@` and returns to the end of the `eval` statement in the event of an otherwise fatal error. Again, this is more expensive than simply executing `BLOCK`, in Perl and in any other language with the facility to trap exceptions (Python, Java).

Comment: In this case he's `eval`ing the result of `-e`.

Comment: Right. It's like saying `$z = -e $path_to_file;eval($z)`, which will ultimately either look like `eval(1)` or `eval(undef)`.